# Conditional statement in FormRequest

Tags: php, laravel-5.3

In my controller I have conditional statement before I validate

```
if ($request->department == 5) {

   $this->validate($request, [
     //validation here
   ];

} else {

   $this->validate($request, [
     //validation here
   ];

}
```

Now I create FormRequest `php artisan make:request DepartmentRequest`

In `method rules()` , I don't know how to access the department parameter, I tried:

`if($request->department == 1)` But threw the `Exception`: Error - undefined `$request` variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `$this->input('department')` inside your form request methods since `FormRequest` extends the `Request` class.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can try do this

```
$request = $this->all();
$department = $request['departement'];
```

Hope this help